# Home url for multilanguage logo

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wpml

I use wpml translate plugin for my two language site and use this code to get different logo for each language version

```
<div class="logo clearfix"> 
<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'): ?> 
<img src="http://ddc.websitedesign.ge/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DDC LOGO_ENG.png"/> 
<?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='ge'): ?> 
<img src="http://ddc.websitedesign.ge/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DDC-LOGO_GEO.png"/> 
<?php endif;?> 
</div>
```

The problem is, that in this case logo doesn't has a homepage link.

I try this way

```
<?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='ge'): ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"/>
<img src="http://ddc.websitedesign.ge/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DDC-LOGO_GEO.png"/> 
<?php endif;?> 
</div>
```

It works. But it breaks the navigation menu. First menu Item goes down.

Just try to use `<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">`

But with the same result.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havent close your link tag with `</a>`:

```
<?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='ge'): ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"/>
<img src="http://ddc.websitedesign.ge/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DDC-LOGO_GEO.png"/>
</a> 
<?php endif;?> 
</div>
```

Also you can add some css rules to your `<a>` html tag this way: `.logo > a { some: rules; }`